# Grails 3.3.6 not firing DocStart and DocEnd Events for command gradle docs

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.3.x

I created a new Grails 3.3.6 application.

Following this document to create documentation for my project: [Grails Docs](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/docs.html)

The above document says to use `gradle docs` or `grails doc` with following arguments..

> Arguments:
>
> --init - Create a template project documentation project (optional)
>
> --pdf - Create PDF output for project documentation (optional)
>
> Fired Events:
>
> DocStart - Before documentation generation begins
>
> DocEnd - After documentation generation completes

I created a scripts folder and added _Events.groovy file with the following contents.

//document-service/scripts/_Events.groovy

```
eventDocStart = { kind ->
    println "**************************** doc start"
}

eventDocEnd = {
    println "**************************** doc end"
}
```

When i run `gradle docs`. Java Docs and groovy docs are running but the events are not getting fired. And `--pdf` argument does not work.

When i run `grails doc`. I get `Command not found doc`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is wrong and this is no longer valid in Grails 3. I overcame my problem by intercepting the gradle docs command.

```
task generateDocs (type: GenerateDocsTask) {}

tasks.groovydoc.dependsOn(generateDocs)

class GenerateDocsTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def docGenerate() {
        List urls = project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.toURI().toURL() }
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls as URL[], (ClassLoader) null)
        def gdocGenerator = classLoader.loadClass("com.rax.DocGenerator").newInstance()
        gdocGenerator.generateGdoc(classLoader)
    }
}
```